# pyexcel export error "No content, file name. Nothing is given"

Tags: python, django, pyexcel, django-excel

I'm using `django-pyexcel` to export data from the website, but when I go to the export URL I get the error:

> Exception Type: IOError
>
> Exception Value: No content, file name. Nothing is given

The code to export the data was copied from the [example](http://django-excel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#handle-data-export) given in the documentation:

```
return excel.make_response_from_a_table(Question, 'xls', file_name="sheet")
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem turned out to be the file format used, `xls` in this case.

I had only installed the `xlsx` (`pyexcel-xlsx`) processor so it did not know how to handle the `xls` file format.

The exception message could have been a bit better as I spent ages trying to figure out if there was a problem with the filename I'd supplied.

Comment: In my case, I didn't even have the `pyexcel-xlsx` processor.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem using Flask app. Try installing the following requirements:

```
numpy==1.21.0
openpyxl==3.0.7
pandas==1.3.0
pyexcel-xlsx==0.6.0
XlsxWriter==1.4.4
```